# How to draw N elements of random indices from numpy array without repetition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say, I have a numpy array defined as:

```
X = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Now I want to draw 3 elements from this array, but with random indices and without repetition, so I'll get, say:

```
X_random_draw = numpy.array([5, 0, 9]
```

How can I achieve something like this with the least effort and with the greatest performance speed? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With NumPy 1.7 or newer, use [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), with `replace=False`:

```
In [85]: X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [86]: np.random.choice(X, 3, replace=False)
Out[86]: array([7, 5, 9])
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I extend this functionality for example for 2D array? Say, `X = numpy.array([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]])` and I want to randomly draw two of X elements so I'll get e.g. `X_rand = numpy.array([[4, 5], [0, 1]])`?

Comment: Select 2 items from `0,...,X.shape[0]`, then use integer indexing: `X[np.random.choice(X.shape[0], 2, replace=False)]`.